# I/O Requests taking longer than 15 seconds, Flush Cache During Replication SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hello I'm primarily a developer but I am trying to troubleshoot our database that basically just locked up last week. I have been diving into this pretty heavily but I'm also a bit out of my league in determining the exact problem.

Facts:

1. SQL Server 2012 SP1 SQL Server VM
2. 8 vcores 6 are used for I/O affinity <- If i turn them all on the machine almost comes to a complete stop during a push replication
3. SAN storage on I want to say 7,200 RPM disks
4. Hosted on an offsite location that should just have a switch in between the storage and the SAN
5. Throughput at the switch is anywhere between 200GB-300GB during replication

Clues so far:

1. During replication heavy times 11PM to 5AM we have multiple error messages of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds sometimes the count is 30K+ other times 1 but a pretty good average of I'd say around 5000. **I/O Issue**
2. During replication times we have multiple Flush cache messages rolling through. **Not sure what this points to**

   3. Latency seems to be sky high **I/O Issue**[image]
   4. Latch_EX and CXPacket are the big offenders but still some IO waits
      [image]
   5. At this point I did some small perfmon test to check the IO because it still looking like there is an IO problem. Note: This was not during the replication and really a low load time. I'll have more stats tomorrow. 
      Avg. Disk sec/Transfer - .0004 Avg .065 Max

Summary:
I have all of this information and I'm still thinking that underlying storage is an issue. What else can I do to build that case or what should I explore more? CXPacket is a parallel problem and could be an issue that starts the whole I/O problem based on my understanding.

I'm planning on:

1. Checking the perfmon report tomorrow.
   **Update**
   [image]
2. Checking to see if file filters are a problem
3. Running diskspd to stress test the underlying storage
4. Getting the I/O affinity right and changing MAXDOP to something a little under 8 so that the server doesn't just die.
5. Figuring out if anything else is taxing the VMHost or VM during those times (Backups in particular)

Comment: You are running on an unsupported old build SQL Server 2012 SP1 which is end of life as of `2015-07-14`. Upgrade to the latest version and then invest your effort in addressing the perf issues. There are many fixes introduced and you might get lucky if what you are encountering is already addressed.

Comment: While you are making some tuning adjustments, you probably want to bump cost for parallelism up from the default of 5 to 50.  Start measuring from there.  Also, what is the storage for the tempdb and log files?  This may be relevant - https://sqlperformance.com/2018/10/sql-performance/three-easy-sql-server-performance-wins

Comment: Basically you are choking your I/O subsystem. Tuning parallelism might to some extent reduce I/O, but I'd be surprised if you see any major differences from that. OTOH, by reducing parallelism, things can go slower and hence do that amount of I/O over a longer time-span. But again, I doubt that is the issue. Other tuning (like tempdb) can *increase* concurrency and as a result put a higher disk load (but over shorter time). So, in the end, you have too much I/O pressure. Tune queries or fix the I/O subsystem. Easier said than done. :-)